# No video for Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: hdmi, video, pi-zero-w

I just received my Pi Zero W and I am a little frustrated. I can't get any video output from it.

First, I tried old SD cards (jessie, kali and libreelec) which were running on the previous A+, B+, Zero - it did not start, the LED is not even turning on. Then I downloaded new updated fresh versions of all OSes including noobs 2.3 and jessie 03.02, burned all "as in manuals" on 3 different SD cards, which I want to mention was perfectly working with the same config, same outputs/inputs devices - the status LED starts, but no video.

How would you advise me to proceed next?

I am guessing that some config should be modified? But then, how come other users did not encounter the same problem? Or did I miss something?

Comment: You haven't accepted an answer. Did you ever get this working? I am having the same problem :-(

Answer (score 6):

Same issue a few days ago. Order of plugged in peripherals mattered. Making sure video out was connected before connecting power.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.  Then I was googling a solution after changing settings countless times.  I left the pi zero w plugged in while searching and noticed after a few minutes it booted as it should.  I am not sure why yet but my pi zero (non w) boots instantly, the pi zero w takes two minutes then starts to post.